# Pandas dataframe merge/join returns NaN

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have two data frames I created using pandas that I am trying to merge to populate the 'W' column on the matching 'Tm' field. When I merge, the new column is seen in the new data frame but half the values return as 'NaN'.

I've tried the following to merge `df_1` and add the 'W' column from `results`.

```
test = df_1.merge(result[['Tm', 'W']], on=['Tm'], how='left')
```

df_1:
[image: dataframe1]

result:

[image: dataframe2]

**OUTPUT**:
[image: output]

I've checked the columns and everything seems to match. Help appreaciated! Thanks.

Comment: Could you confirm that teams that have a NaN against them after merge actually have a record in results dataframe? Because your merge looks fine.

Comment: Why is there "Baltimore Ravens (1)" in `result`, and in `output` it is just "Baltimore Ravens"?

Comment: As this is a left merge, have you checked that the value exists in the right table 'result' as well

Comment: You're merging on team names, i.e. strings. Is the data in both dfs from the same source? Did you do quality checks and clean the data? There could be differences in the name strings that aren't readily visible or the more apparent difference that bernie pointed out. An inner join might be one way to check if there are any hidden differences.

Comment: In addition to the good questions some of the other commenters have raised, please share code/data as text in the post itself, not as images! See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/11301900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that output row for *Kansas City Chiefs* contains *NaN*
in *W* column looks obvious:

- *df_1* contains in this row just *Kansas City Chiefs*,
- but *result* contains a row for *Kansas City Chiefs (2)*.

Note the trailing *(2)*. It causes that there is no match between these rows.
The reason for other cases on *NaN* is probably the same.

Apparently you should first get rid of these trailing numbers (and surrounding
parentheses and the space preceding them) and then perform your merge.